# Create PDF Document in VBA

Tags: vba, pdf-generation

Using VBA outside of the MS-Office suite of applications, is there a good way to create a PDF document, or another light-weight document that can be converted to a PDF?

I have data within classes, which I want to get into a PDF, how do I do that quickly, without resorting to opening up MS Word, MS Excel, etc?

Comment: You could have a look at the cutepdf api: http://www.cutepdf.com/solutions/formsdk.asp  I don't think it's a free product though (I know cutePDF has a free component, but the development stuff, I think, is a product you have to license).

Comment: Saving a document in Word or Excel via VBA takes about 4-5 lines of code, just saying...

Comment: Agreed, it only takes a few lines of code, but it has a relatively large cost when compared to what I am trying to do.  The startup time of Word or Excel, will eat into the time that I am trying to save by using VBA.  I appreciate the suggestion, I just don't think it is the right fit.

Answer (score 0):

This link seems like it might be helpful with solving your issue.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/840511

According to the information there you can print to the adobe pdf virtual printer and it will generate the file. The people on that forum were doing something with emailing the file afterwards and generating the file from access data, but it looks like a solution that will work for any VBA project.

Comment: I think that would work if I had something to print.  My problem is that I have data, but nothing to print, there is no document or screen to use, it's just data.  I need to create a document in order for any solution I've found thus far to work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the pdf if you don't have anything that needs to be printed? Are you trying to dynamically generate the pdf from the data in classes that you have?

Comment: You nailed it, I am trying to dynamically create the PDF based on data that I have.